# Search and Replace in files from windows command prompt

Tags: powershell, templates, batch-file

I've two files 
properties.txt

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

and template.txt which uses this file

```
$key1 xcvsdf sfd $key1 sdf 
$key2 lorem $key2 ipsum
```

I want to replace all the properties from properties.txt with template.txt and write it to a file.
I don't want it to run on python\java runtime since it should run on any machine without prerequirements

How can I do that using powershell? batch files?

Comment: When asking questions it is preferred that you show some effort in what you have tried. You have a code writing request (which is discouraged) here and you haven't even nailed down a language.

Comment: I don't agree with you: I want to do search and replace without runtime environments on Windows. The two answers mathias and @Aacini below are exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this needs to be able to run on PowerShell 2.0, this is what I would do:

```
# Read template from file
$template = Get-Content .\template.txt

# Copy template to result variable
$result = $template

# Loop through list of properties
Get-Content C:\dev\properties.txt |ForEach-Object{
    # Split each line into key-value pairs
    $key,$value = $_ -split '=',2
    # Replace the placeholder with the appropriate value
    $result = $result -replace ('\${0}' -f $key),$value
}

# Output final result
$result |Out-File .\result.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load the set of replacement values from properties.txt
set "n=0"
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (properties.txt) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "key[!n!]=%%a"
   set "value[!n!]=%%b"
)

rem Process template.txt file
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (template.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   rem Process each replacement value
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (
      for /F "tokens=1,2" %%x in ("!key[%%i]! !value[%%i]!") do (
         set "line=!line:$%%x=%%y!"
      )
   )
   echo !line!
)) > output.txt
```

output.txt:

```
value1 xcvsdf sfd value1 sdf
value2 lorem value2 ipsum
```

This code remove the exclamation marks that may appear in template.txt file. This point may be fixed, if needed.